# Can someone help me to understand the solution for Leetcode's Self-Dividing-Numbers exercise

Tags: javascript

Here's the link to the exercise:
https://leetcode.com/problems/self-dividing-numbers/

I have the code but I'm having trouble understanding how to explain it after calling the first map method.

`.map((integer) => integer !== 0 && number % integer === 0)`
This checks to see whether the single integer in the array of integers is not 0(because a SDN can't contain 0) and whether the number is self-divisible by the integer. Is this explanation correct? What would the array look like if we were to return it after calling the 2nd map method?

As for the reduce method, I'm completely lost. Why was it used?

Thanks

```
var SDN = function(number) {

    // change number to string
    // use split to get number string to be an array of integers as strings
    // map(Number) to change array of strings to array of numbers

    return number.toString()
                .split('')
                .map(Number)
                .map((integer) => integer !== 0 && number % integer === 0)
                .reduce((a,b) => a && b)
}

var selfDividingNumbers = function(left, right) {
    let res = []
    for(let i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        if(SDN(i)) {
            res.push(i)
        }
    }
    return res
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `.map((integer) => integer !== 0 && number % integer === 0)` This checks to see whether the single integer in the array of integers is not 0(because a SDN can't contain 0) and whether the number is self-divisible by the integer. Is this explanation correct?

Correct.

> What would the array look like if we were to return it after calling the 2nd map method?

It would be an array of true or false values, with each value depending on the conditions you explain above.

> As for the reduce method, I'm completely lost. Why was it used?

The reduce method takes the array of true or false values, and then and's them all sequentially. This will return a single true or false value, essentially representing the question "were all of the values true?".

---

As an expansion on the `reduce` explanation, reduce expects a callback function which takes two arguments; a previous value and a current value. In addition, there may be a seed for the first value of previous (which was not used in your example). reduce will then iterate and inject the previous value and current value into the callback function, using the return as the next previous value.

```
reduce(function(previous, current){ ... }, optionalSeedForFirstPrevious)
```

Using the example you give, this would mean that `a` was the previous value, and `b` was the current value. The arrow function returns the result of `a && b` each time.

So, if you have `[true, false, true]`, that means that reduce will essentially evaluate as

```
iteration1 = true && false;
iteration2 = iteration1 && true;
return iteration2; //false
```

if you have `[true, true, true]`, that means that reduce will essentially evaluate as

```
iteration1 = true && true;
iteration2 = iteration1 && true;
return iteration2; //true
```

For more information on [reduce, visit the Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Say we're working on the number `13`. After calling the second map method, would   `[1,3]` turn to `[true,false]` and the reduce method would return `false` because T&&F===F?

Comment: @tableguarder - Yes, that is exactly what would happen.